# Is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is the difference between  $S^1 \times [0,1]$ and $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$

I know that  $S^1 \times [0,1]$ denote the cylinder and it is homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1$

Here ,Im confused about $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.

My question :

$1.$ what is the meaning of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}?$

$2.$ Is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$   homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1?$ Yes/No

Comment: one difference is that one is compact and the other is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ is the product space of a circle with the real number line. It is an infinitely long cylinder, for the same reason that $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ is a regular cylinder.

It is still homotopy equivalent to a circle, because $\mathbb{R}$ is homotopy equivalent to a point, and so $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\times\{*\} \cong S^1.$